# How do I split and replace a specific char in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, replace, splice

I am trying to create a function that auto formats the text box as the user is typing in their Canadian Postal Code.

This is my original function, but the problem is that it doesn't catch if the person writes in the wrong format.
EX. AA1 10A when it should always be in the format of A0A 0A0.

```
        $("#tbPostalCode").on("change keyup paste", function(){
            var output;
            var input = $(this).val();
            input = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
          input = input.toUpperCase();
            var front = input.substr(0, 3);
            var end = input.substr(3, 5);
            if (front.length < 3) {
                output = front;
            } else if (front.length == 3 && end.length < 3) {
                output = front+ " " + end;
            } else if (front.length == 3 && end.length == 3) {
                output = front+ " " + end;
            }
            $(this).val(output);
        });
```

This is what I have been trying to make work. To basically split the string and replace the specific spots of the index according to the regEx requirements. So I am just trying to figure out how to make this work.

```
        $("#tbPostalCode").on("change keyup paste", function(){
            var output;
            var input = $(this).val();
    input = input.splice("");
            input[1,4,6] = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    input[0,2,5] = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'');
          input = input.toUpperCase();
            var front = input.substr(0, 3);
            var end = input.substr(3, 5);
            if (front.length < 3) {
                output = front;
            } else if (front.length == 3 && end.length < 3) {
                output = front+ " " + end;
            } else if (front.length == 3 && end.length == 3) {
                output = front+ " " + end;
            }
            $(this).val(output);
        });
```

Code Block 1 Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jessica_mather123/730gj842/7/

Code Block 2 Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jessica_mather123/f21sx97j/

This is the RegEx I want it to follow:

```
[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z][ -]?\d[A-Za-z]\d
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/sequoKLqL3tyxyVo)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what is allowed?  I can't see the difference between AA1 10A and A0A 0A0.

Comment: For a Canadian Postal code it has to be:    alpha,num,alpha num,alpha,num. So the 1,3,5 always have to be alphabetical, but 2,4,6 always have to be numeric. So essentially I always want to be in that format.

Comment: I do not understand what the behaviour should be: what happens if I enter "99999" everything gets deleted? and what if I write AA1, wouldn't that be impossible if you're erasing the second A?

Comment: So, if user types in "aa" what do you want the textbox to do?  Erase the second a automatically?  Turn the second a red, or bold it, or show a tooltip, or what?

Comment: Basically, I want to to erase anytime a letter is put in the spots 2,4 or 6.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML5 input validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) handles this pretty well across browsers.  Automatically deleting input without providing notice as to what is going on makes for a confusing UI experience.  Try HTML input/form validation.  You can plug your regex right in there...

Comment: I already have that in place as well as an error message as precaution. I was just hoping it would be possible to do it this way. But if not this is a good solution. Thanks!